# iOS Mail Message View like UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview, uiscrollview

The Mail Message View is as I see it a scroll view with a container, the container again has a header (including the from, date, and subject field) and the content webview.

Now when you zoom in the webview, the header stays at the same place and size.

Is it possible to do a view like this with the public APIs? I see as problem that the UIWebView is not a subclass of UIScrollView, so it's not like a scroll view in a scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Apple Developer Forum this question was discussed under [UIWebView in a UITableView](https://devforums.apple.com/message/105899), and Penso published an example implementation: [webview-in-tableview](http://github.com/penso/webview-in-tableview). But the implementation doesn't behave 100% like Mail one.

Answer (score 1):

Injecting javascript into UIWebView will do some extent of job but zooming is still a problem. i.e. we can't zoom only a details of mail body leaving the other parts like To, Cc, Bcc, Subject unzoomed.

Answer (score -1):

You can place a UIWebView inside of a UIScrollView from Interface Builder or programmatically.

Comment: it's not about the placing, it's the scrolling & zooming behavior I wanna have exactly like in the Mail Message View

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good and safe idea. As Apple said in documentation: "Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled"

Comment: That is correct, however many many commercial products do it. The trick is to disable scrolling in the web view.